# PHP class declaration explanation needed

Tags: php, class, object

Example 3 on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

1. What is **Test $other** in `function baz(Test $other)`, i got that $other is argument for function however why Test and space is before it?
2. whats the point of passing "test" and "other" arguments when initiating class they do anything?
3. Whats the big deal about calling private method in this example?

   ```
   class Test {
       private $foo;

       public function __construct($foo) {
           $this->foo = $foo;
       }

       private function bar() {
           echo 'Accessed the private method.';
       }

       public function baz(Test $other) {
           // We can change the private property:
           $other->foo = 'hello';
           var_dump($other->foo);

           // We can also call the private method:
           $other->bar();
       }
   }    

   $test = new Test('test');

   $test->baz(new Test('other'));
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a parameter of a class typed `Test`
2. It's an internal string, for naming, configuration, initialization, etc.
3. You don't want to expose the full API to all objects. It clutters up the visibility and some methods are not meant to be seen by others - for example when you want to clean up things, manage resources and so on.

This is a bare minimum example with no function and therefore not the best learning resource either.

Comment: 1. okay so $other is just argument of function baz() can you explain exactly what class name spaced before it doing any manual reference to such declaration?   
2. i see its argument for _construct function however i don't see strings `test` and `other` appear anywhere in class itself.  
3. in this particular example why they emphasize private versus public method i mean this is not a key point of that example isn't it?

Comment: I would just say that the PHP documentation isn't the best learning resource.